# discard elements from list recursively r

Tags: r, na, purrr

I have a nested list with some NAs, and I want to discard the NAs from the list.

`purrr::discard` does not work recursively:

```r
l <- list(a = NA, b = T, c = c(F, F))
purrr::discard(l, is.na)
```

Throws this error:

> Error: Predicate functions must return a single TRUE or FALSE, not a logical vector of length 2

I would like to end up with the following list in this case:

`l2 <- list(b = T, c = c(F, F))`

(purrr version: 0.3.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is.na(c(T,T,T))` returns `c(F,F,F)`. To use discard, the function needs to return a single value for each list element as the error suggests.

This should work.

```
purrr::discard(l,function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

This will work only if all the elements in an index of the list are NA.

To remove all `NA` elements this should work

```
library(tidyverse)
l <- list(a = NA, b = c(T,NA), c = c(F, F)) # Define a list
lapply(l,function(x) x[!is.na(x)])%>% # Remove all nested NA's
   purrr::discard(.,function(x) length(x) == 0) # Remove all empty elements
```

Comment: it's not recursive though

Comment: It isn't recursive, but I don't think a recursive solution is required for this problem. Perhaps we can change the title of the question?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT(another option)**

```
 purrr::discard(l,function(x) isTRUE(anyNA(x)))
$b
[1] TRUE

$c
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

You can identify all `NA` elements and `zap` them:

```
 purrr::list_modify(l,a=purrr::zap())
$b
[1] TRUE

$c
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to remove all nested `NA`s, you can write up a helper `zap_if()`:

```
 zap_if <- function(x){
       unlist(lapply(x, function(z) z[!is.na(z)]))
    }
    purrr::map(l,zap_if)
```

Result:

```
    $a
    [1] 1

    $b
    [1] TRUE

    $c
    [1] FALSE FALSE
```

Data for the `zap_if` part:

```
l <- list(a = c(NA,1), b = T, c = c(F, F))
```

Comment: I think `zap` is from `rlang`?

Comment: @Sada93 It's imported from `rlang` hence calling `purrr` still calls it.

Comment: @akrun Currently on phone. Will check it later.

Comment: @akrun Not sure about the structure of OP's data. Here we had only a with a single `NA`, so not sure if there were other list elements with all `NA`s in which case using `all` is perhaps most appropriate.

Comment: Its okay.  i got a bit curious about the function behavior